# Angular *ngFor doesn't updates the View

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

When I update my servers Array from outside of the class declaration, the View/HTML-Component doesn't update the View. When I do the same from inside the class, it works. Both Functions do update the servers Array. But only the inner function causes the DOM to update. See Code ->

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  cdr: ChangeDetectorRef;
  
   @Input() servers: Server[] = [];

   constructor( cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cdr = cdr;
   }

   addServerToServerListInsideClass() { //That's the Test-Function that works
    this.servers.push(new Server("test", "test"));
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}

export function addServerToServerList(contentComponent: ContentComponent, name: string, content: string) {
  const newServer = new Server(name, content);
  contentComponent.servers.push(newServer);
  contentComponent.servers.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
  });
  contentComponent.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

Here the template with the *ngFor loop->

```
<button (click)="addServerToServerListInsideClass()">My Button</button> <!-- test inside function-->
<div *ngFor="let server of servers | keyvalue">
    <app-content-item [key]="server.key" [value]="server.value"></app-content-item>
</div>
```

The exported function from outside the class declaration is called in another .ts File. See Code ->

```
export class EingabeComponent implements OnInit {

  serverName!: string; 
  serverContent!: string;

  constructor(public contentComponent: ContentComponent) { 
  }

  onUpdateServerName(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.serverName =  target.value;
  }

  onUpdateServerContent(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.serverContent = target.value;
  }

  onCreateServer() {
    addServerToServerList(this.contentComponent, this.serverName, this.serverContent);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And the onCreateServer() function is called in the following template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Add new Server or blueprints</h1>
        <label for="name">Server Name</label>
        <input
            type="text" name="name"
            (input)="onUpdateServerName($event)">

         <label for="content">Server Content</label>
         <input
            type="text" name="content"
            (input)="onUpdateServerContent($event)">

        <button class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="onCreateServer()">Add Server
         Add Server </button>
    </div>                       
</div>
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy: onPush` ?

Comment: Yes, I do ->   
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to execute a .ts method from a different ts file, try using ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

Use  ngOnChanges to detect

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class ContentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {

  cdr: ChangeDetectorRef;
  
   @Input() servers: Server[] = [];

   constructor( cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cdr = cdr;
   }

   addServerToServerListInsideClass() { //That's the Test-Function that works
    this.servers.push(new Server("test", "test"));
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes)
    // if changes && isNotFistchanges ---> this.servers = changes.servers
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I am understanding your problem exactly, but if you have a component that it working when you execute addServerToServerListInsideClass() and you want to execute that method from a different .ts file, just create a ViewChild to execute it:

```
  @ViewChild(ContentComponent, { static: true })
  contentComponent!: ContentComponent;
```

then execute like this:

```
contentComponent.addServerToServerListInsideClass();
```